# What data am I supposed to pass to the 2D array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

i want to create a 3 by 4 array and set values to all those fields. The values are all strings resulting from scanner objects. The problem is, as you can see, i don't know which variable to pass as the values of each field of my array. any ideas?

```
 import java.util.*;

 public class multArray {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         String name, LastName, gender, age, value;
         int i, j, x;
         int y = 4;
         int row = 3;
         int col = 4;
         String[][] array = new String[4][3];

         for (x = 0; x < y; x++) {
             System.out.println("Input first name");
             Scanner kbin1 = new Scanner(System.in);
             String name = kbin1.next();

             System.out.println("Input last name");
             Scanner kbin2 = new Scanner(System.in);
             String LastName = kbin2.next();
             System.out.println("Input gender");
             Scanner kbin3 = new Scanner(System.in);
             String gender = kbin3.next();
             System.out.println("input age");
             Scanner kbin4 = new Scanner(System.in);
             String age = kbin4.next();

             for (i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                 for (j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                     array[i][j] = ? ? ? ? ;
                 }
             }
         }

         for (i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
             for (j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                 System.out.println(array[i][j] + " ");
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Using a 2D-array like this is bad practice. Create a `Person` class that contains the `lastname`, `firstname`, `gender` and `age`. This will make everything easier and clearer.

Comment: @Obicere While that is good advice, I am under the impression the user is new to JAVA and needs to use 2D arrays and may be highly unfamiliar with classes and OOP.

Comment: Thnks to you all, i have decided to take Obicere advice

Answer (score 0):

What I see is you are iterating 4 times or getting input from user 4 times

```
for (x=0; x<y; x++ )
```

instead of putting it the value in a 2 for loops just use the `x` value as the current row index from the outer loop

**example:**

**instead:**

```
    for (i=0; i < row.length; i++) { 

        for (j=0; j< col.length; j++){
            array [i][j]= ????;
            }
        }
```

**use this:**

```
j = 0;
array [x][j] = name
array [x][j++] = LastName; 
array [x][j++] = gender;
array [x][j++] = age;
```

where `x` is the row and `j` is the column

Also make your 2D array 3 rows 4 column

```
new String [3] [4] //3 rows 4 column
```

Comment: Last part is wrong, since OP mentioned having a 3x4 table (meaning 4 entries per row), I'm assuming he wants name + lastName separate

Comment: @thinlyveiledquestionmark actually his 2D array is 4 rows 3 column that why i appended firstname and last name

Comment: He has mentioned he wanted to create a "3 by 4 array", which means 3 rows, 4 columns, 3x, 4y

Answer (score 0):

Since you needed a 3 x 4 array, you can easily do the following:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
for (int x = 0; x < row; x++) {
     System.out.println("Input first name");
     String name = scan.next();

     System.out.println("Input last name");
     String LastName = scan.next();

     System.out.println("Input gender");
     String gender = scan.next();

     System.out.println("input age");
     String age = scan.next();

     int j = 0;
     array [x][j] = name
     array [x][j++] = LastName; 
     array [x][j++] = gender;
     array [x][j++] = age;
}
```

Two things. One, you don't need to create separate Scanner objects for each user input; you can reuse the same Scanner object to take the other inputs. Second, it would do you good to choose more "uniform" variable names. So instead of:

```
String namee;
String LastName;
String gender;
String age;
```

It'd be much better to pick something more concise like:

```
String firstName, lastName, gender, age;
```